# Extended regular expression grouping

Tags: grep, posix-ere

Trying to understand grouping in extended regular expressions. What is the difference between following two extended regular expressions.

```
$ echo "the CPU is" | grep -E '[Tt]he CPU|computer is'
the CPU is
$ echo "the CPU is" | grep -E '[Tt]he (CPU|computer) is'
the CPU is
```

On my Ubuntu `bash` shell the `grep` program in the former pattern highlights `the CPU` in red color. In the latter pattern `grep` highlights `the CPU is`. How is `grouping` change the pattern matching in the two cases above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are not equivalent! For example:

```bash
$ cat ip.txt
xyz The CPU 123
get the CPU and book
the computer is not here
The CPU is bad

$ grep -E '[Tt]he CPU|computer is' ip.txt
xyz The CPU 123
get the CPU and book
the computer is not here
The CPU is bad

$ grep -E '[Tt]he (CPU|computer) is' ip.txt
the computer is not here
The CPU is bad
```

- `[Tt]he CPU|computer is` matches `[Tt]he CPU` OR `computer is`
- `[Tt]he (CPU|computer) is` matches `[Tt]he CPU is` OR `[Tt]he computer is`

Similar to `a(b+c)d = abd+acd` in maths, you get `a(b|c)d = abd|acd` in regular expressions.